# LDAP groups and SonarQube configuration

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

We are planning to implement LDAP configuration in SonarQube settings.
So in sonar.properties file it is as follows

```
(&(objectClass=user)
(|(memberOf=CN=GL_group,OU=Groups,DC=project,DC=company,DC=com))
(sAMAccountName={login}))
```

Now we are planning to create Active Directory (AD) group for all project and then we will add this in `GL_group` of AD group.

We will also add project group in SonarQube to Sync with AD.

My question is, will this work? i.e.:

- Add new project group in AD
- Add this group in `GL_group` in AD
- User logged into Sonar
- User is automatically added to project group

Will it be added to `GL_group` OR project group?

### LDAP settings

```
sonar.security.realm:                      LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword:               false
sonar.authenticator.createUsers:           true
ldap.url:                                  ldap://sonar.engagement.project.country.company.com:389
ldap.bindDn:                               svc_user
ldap.bindPassword:                         password
ldap.authentication:                       simple
ldap.user.baseDn:                          DC=engagement,DC=project,DC=country,DC=company,DC=com
ldap.user.request:                         (&(objectClass=user)(|(memberOf=CN=GL_projectEngagementUsers,OU=projectGroups,DC=engagement,DC=project,DC=country,DC=company,DC=com))(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute:               displayName
ldap.user.emailAttribute:                  mail
ldap.group.baseDn:                         DC=engagement,DC=project,DC=country,DC=company,DC=com
ldap.group.idAttribute:                    cn
ldap.group.request:                        (&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the instructions given on the [LDAP plugin documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin), and more precisely if you activate the group mapping, you will be able to achieve what you described.

Comment: I have added LDAP settings in my question, can you please ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I can't check those parameters, only you can do it.

Comment: Frabric, 
I mean i have shared LDAP settings with AD group called GL_projectEngagementUsers
Now i know that if i create same group in Sonar and then when user logged in, it will be automatically added to this group

But what if i create new AD group called GL_ProjectGroup and added it in above group and then add user in it, so when logged into Sonar, will it be added to GL_ProjectGroup ?
Hope this time i am clear